# how to remove the youtube video precise seeking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube-api

Question:

How can I remove the "precise seeking" feature from a YouTube video? The feature that allows you to skip forward or backward in a video by small increments is causing some issues for my viewers. Can this feature be disabled? Thank you.

Comment: Are you working with embedding?